# Rota-baxter operator on Hopf algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

how to define rota-baxter operator on hopf algebra?
we have know the notion of rota-baxter operator on cocommutative Hopf algebra,but if the hopf algebra is noncocommutative?